# mulitple html pages one js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My website has multiple html pages and sliders in them.

I'm using Bxslider and
some pages also have Owl Carousel, but i dont want to have multiple .js file to call different sliders on each page.

Can i make just one js file and use the above code for example on all of the pages. Like this, calling all sliders in one .js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
});
```

I don't want to include both plugins(owl-carousel and bxslider) js file in every pages that don't need it.

Does it effects performance to call the slider on pages that dont have that slider ?

Thanks !

Comment: It will cause syntax errors to call a plugin on a page where it is not loaded.

Comment: you can wrap that code in `try catch` block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's fine to do, and it won't affect performance because when you do

```
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
```

And there's nothing that matches the #owl-example selector, it won't return any elements so .owlCarousel() will not be called.

So not only can you do it on one js file with those generic calls, I would encourage it as it's the best way to go about it - that way if you need to change the carousel functionality, it's all in one place.

Comment: @SevanD. I wouldn't load the plugins if they aren't needed...Just check if the elements exist like in my answer that way you aren't unnecessarily loading javascript files (plugins) that aren't needed.

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if the page has the slider before you call the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.bxslider').length > 0)
    {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    }
    if($('#owl-example').length > 0)
    {  
        $('#owl-example').owlCarousel();
    }
});
```